# How do I change the direction of a speech bubble in Preview?

Tags: preview

I'm using Preview to add some speech bubbles to a picture.  The default speech bubble assumes the speaker is below and to the left.  Can I change where the speech is coming from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes!

You can drag the text bubble bounding box (the blue dots that you would use to resize the bubble) over to the other side.

This effectively over-"resizes" the bubble so it is mirrored.

Answer (score 5):

Just drag the cursor starting from the direction where you want the point to be.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can simply drag the corner selection (the round dot) to the other side

Like this

[image: speech bubble]